# snap home read plug kdenlive on 20.04

Tags: permissions, 20.04, snap, kdenlive

How do I get kdenlive to open files on a shared user other than my own home directory?

Do I have to change the value of the snap home interface read-plug to "all"? If so, how to achieve this?

Comment: I also installed the snap version and cannot load files from outside the home directory. I had the same issue on other applications as well. Is it a "feature" of snaps?

Comment: It is not exactly what I want but I made /mnt a shared folder and ran this command in the terminal:
'sudo snap connect kdenlive:removable-media'
Now kdelive has permission to read/write to the /mnt folder.
Anyone who can tell how to make a shared home folder accessible for kdenlive?

Answer (score 0):

You still need to make the folder readable by others. You can right click on the file (depending on which file manager you are using, this will look different), and choose "Properties", then under "permissions", allow the folder to be read by others.

[image]